# Returning a list to view and manipulating it in MVC3, Database first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a function that triggers a stored procedure that runs a 
select * from tbl_admin where id=".." and username=".."
The returned output of the select statement is stored in a complex return type object spa_user_Result and stored onto a list.

I want to pass this list to the view and use it to display data, How do I do that?? 
code is smthing like this:

```
   public ViewResult Index()
        {
            <spa_users_Result> result = new <spa_users_Result>();
            System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<spa_users_Result> r;
            r = db.adminUser("s","superuser");

            result = (<spa_users_Result>)r.ToList();

            return View();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your object(s) to the `View` method

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
  var result =  db.adminUser("s","superuser").ToList();
  return View(result );
}
```

Assuming your `db.adminUser("s","superuser")` method returns a Collection of `spa_users_Result` object.

Make your View strongly typed to List of spa_users_Result object

```
@model IEnumerable<spa_users_Result>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Name</p>
}
```

Assuming your `spa_users_Result` class has a Property called `Name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what level of detail you're looking for with this question, but passing the list to the view is as simple as:

```
return View(result);
```

EDIT:  Also don't you want result to be a list?

```
List<spa_users_Result> result = new List<spa_users_Result>();
```